# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'

Tags: angular, typescript, types, interface

I keep getting this error of types not matching however I have stated the types in both the interface and sub class constructor.

The subclass

```
import { Type } from '@angular/core';

export class StepItem {
  constructor(public component: Type<any>,
     public stepName: string,
     public buttonText: string,
     public active: boolean,
     public disabled: boolean,
     public stepButton: boolean,
     public lastItem: boolean,
     public uniqueId?: string,
     public order?: number,
     public mainStep?: boolean,
     public hideDropdownArrow?: boolean,
     public mainDropdown?: boolean,
     public subStepLevel1?: boolean,
     public subStepLevel2?: boolean,
     public mainStepDisabled?: boolean,
     public MainstepName?: string,
     public mainStepUniqueId?: string,
     public dropdown?: boolean, 
     
    ) { }
}
```

the interface:

```
export interface StepComponent {
    stepName: string;
    buttonText: string;
    active: boolean;
    disabled: boolean;
    stepButton: boolean;
    lastItem: boolean;
    uniqueId?: string;
    order?: number;
    mainStep?: boolean;
    hideDropdownArrow?: boolean;
    mainDropdown?: boolean;
    subStepLevel1?: boolean;
    subStepLevel2?: boolean;
    mainStepDisabled?: boolean;
    MainstepName?: string;
    mainStepUniqueId?: string;
    dropdown?: boolean;
}
```

The errors:

[image: error message]

[image: error message]

The weird part is I have done the same for the other properties but some work some don't, I have restarted VS code but problem persists. I have even added the properties in the service and given them types?

Any ideas would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Could you please provide the parts of the code were the error occurs?

Comment: Update: I was passing the values in as params so the order in the service object had to match. Which is not ideal as sometimes not all the props are needed. Changed sub class to: import { Type } from '@angular/core';

export class StepItem {
  constructor(public component: Type<any>, public data: any) { }
}

and interface to export interface StepComponent {
    data: any;

Comment: Its not ideal as I want the stepItems[] object to reflect the types and available options inside when using it in another component... hmm